# How to filter values from a multi index Pandas data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a multi index pandas data frame `df` as below:

```
                Count
Letter Direction           
A       -1          3
         1          0
B       -1          2
         1          4
C       -1          4
         1          10
D       -1          8
         1          1
E       -1          4
         1          5
F       -1          1
         1          1
```

I want to filter out `Letters` which has `Count < 2` in both or either one of the direction.
Tried `df[df.Count < 2]`, but its giving the below output:

```
                Count
Letter Direction           
A        1          0
D        1          1
F       -1          1
         1          1
```

Desired output is as below,

```
                Count
Letter Direction           
A       -1          3
         1          0
D       -1          8
         1          1
F       -1          1
         1          1
```

what should i do to get the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with boolean mask and [`GroupBy.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html) - `any` check if at least one `True` per first level of `MultiIndex` and `transform` return `mask` with same size like original DataFrame, so possible filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[(df.Count < 2).groupby(level=0).transform('any')]
print (df)
                  Count
Letter Direction       
A      -1             3
        1             0
D      -1             8
        1             1
F      -1             1
        1             1
```

Another solution is use [`MultiIndex.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.get_level_values.html) for get values of `Letter` by condition and select by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df = df.loc[df.index.get_level_values(0)[df.Count < 2]]
print (df)
                  Count
Letter Direction       
A      -1             3
        1             0
D      -1             8
        1             1
F      -1             1
        1             1
```